How to use other tables' colmun for grouping in Django
I tried to use other tables' colmun for grouping data.
print(Classes.objects.values('name', 'students__testresults__tests__name'))

And then I got the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...Framework_practice\django\model\ModelExam\model_exam.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(Classes.objects.values('name', 'students__testresults__tests__name'))
  File ...Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1360, in values
    clone = self._values(*fields, **expressions)
  File "...\Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1355, in _values
    clone.query.set_values(fields)
  File "...Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 2502, in set_values
    self.add_fields(field_names, True)
  File "...Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 2208, in add_fields
    cols.append(join_info.transform_function(target, final_alias))
  File "...Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1889, in transform
    wrapped = previous(field, alias)
  File "...\Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1890, in transform
    return self.try_transform(wrapped, name)
  File "...Framework_practice\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1427, in try_transform
    raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'tests' for BigAutoField or join on the field not permitted.

Process finished with exit code 1


models.py is following
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Tests(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table='tests'


class TestResults(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Students', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    test_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Tests', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    score = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table='testreults'


class Students(models.Model):
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Classes', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table='students'


class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table='classes'

asgiref==3.8.1
Django==5.0.4
pytz==2024.1
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.11.0
tzdata==2024.1

This is the env.
Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I have looked but sincerely couldn't find it.
print(Classes.objects.values('name', 'students__testresults__score'))
this code works in the same file of the error code.
Therefore I thought I could use other tables' columns by {table name}__{colmun name}.

TestResult has a ForeignKey named test_id, so:
print(Classes.objects.values('name', 'students__testresults__test_id__name'))
Normally one does not add a suffix …_id to a ForeignKey field, since Django will automatically add a "twin" field with an …_id suffix. Therefore it should be test, instead of test_id.
So then it would be:
print(Classes.objects.values('name', 'students__testresults__test__name'))
Your TestResult also spans a many-to-many relation between Students and Tests, so we can short-circuit with:
class Tests(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tests'


class TestResults(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.ForeignKey('Tests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'testreults'


class Students(models.Model):
    class_id = models.ForeignKey('Classes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Tests, through='TestResults')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'students'
Then we can simplify to:
print(Classes.objects.values('name', 'students__tests__name'))


Note: normally a Django model is given a singular name, so Student instead of Students.


It worked. I misunderstood how to access another table when the table has a foreign key. Thank you for your help.
